# Magento2 Auto generated coupons are not working?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, coupon-codes

I am using Magento2 enterprice edition 2.1.2

Magneto2 specific coupons are working well.

When created a cart price rule with coupon as a "auto" and generated multiple coupons in Manage Coupon code.
When used this coupon code magento showing all coupons are invalid.

Please check attached screen-shot's

[enter image description here][1][image]

[image]

Comment: facing same problem.

Comment: are you fixed it?

Comment: i found it: https://youtu.be/4B_9sWsJcYM , you can follow step of video

Comment: In my case the issue is To Date. It was set too far ahead i.e. 09/30/2117. When I cross checked, it was working upto 2035.

Answer (score 1):

Since code generator is also become part of consumer queue after 2.3.x ,
you can manually run this command to start generating the coupon codes,

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a bug on Magento 2.1. There is a difference about the type of coupon which auto-generate
To fix it. Go to file vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule/Collection.php

```
 
$orWhereConditions = [
    $connection->quoteInto(
        '(main_table.coupon_type = ? AND rule_coupons.type = 0)',
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO
    ),
    ....
];
```

Then change rule_coupons.type = 0 to rule_coupons.type = 1
Hope that this will help everyone